# Rewriting jQuery.ajax post into fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fetch

I have a service, which asynchronously calls a REST API. I have a piece of jQuery, which works as intended, but I want to rewrite it using [JS fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). However, it doesn't seem to post the correct data to the server. All I get in response from the server is **"Missing parameter: userId"**.

Below is my working jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http:/myservice.com/users/delete',
  data: { userId: myVar },
  type:'post',
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }
});
```

I assumed the code would be simply:

```
fetch('http:/myservice.com/users/delete', {
  method: 'post',
  body: { userId: myVar }
}).then(function(response) {
   return response.text()
});
```

If I look at the XHR request in the original code, it actually posts form data. So I tried to rewrite:

```
fetch('http:/myservice.com/users/delete', {
  method: 'post',
  body: new FormData({ userId: myVar })
}).then(function(response) {
   return response.text()
});
```

I've also tried other variations of the code, such as sending it as a hardcoded string (`userId=1337`) or using `JSON.stringify`.

What am I doing wrong? Am I not understanding fetch correctly? Is there anything more I can do to debug?

Comment: _I want to rewrite it using fetch._ What exactly `fetch` do you mean? Is it part of some framework?

Comment: @hindmost https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Have you tried creating the `FormData` object and then using `append("userId", myVar);`, rather than instantiate it with an object?

Comment: `FormData` [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) expects DOM element, not plain object (`{ userId: myVar }`). Use `append` method as @Archer suggested, or [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object with URL search string instead of `FormData`.

Comment: @hindmost I solved it by appending it directly to the URL as search parameters. Feel free to add an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Building the body does require some tinkering.

Try the below code:

```
var serialize = function (data) {
    return Object.keys(data).map(function (keyName) {
        return encodeURIComponent(keyName) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[keyName])
    }).join('&');
};

fetch('http:/myservice.com/users/delete', {
  method: 'post',
  body: serialize({ userId: myVar })
}).then(function(response) {
   return response.text()
});
```